# VB Overloads Textboxt BorderStyle Property giving error "Specified cast is not valid."

Tags: vb.net, textbox, user-controls, overloading

I created a User Control where a TextBox has a border only on bottom part.
Please see image. https://ibb.co/nbJEMK

My problem is when I am using the control on other project and resizing the textbox I am getting an error "Specified cast is not valid." Is Overloads something to do with this?

```
'In Module
Public Enum BorderStyle As Byte
    None = 0
    FixedSingle = 1
    Fixed3D = 2
    FixedBottom = 3
End Enum


Public Class TextBox
    Inherits Windows.Forms.TextBox

    Private _label As Windows.Forms.Label = Nothing
    Private _borderColor As Drawing.Color = Drawing.Color.Black
    Private _borderStyle As BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None

    Public Property BorderColor As Drawing.Color
        Get
            Return Me._borderColor
        End Get
        Set(value As Drawing.Color)
            Me._borderColor = value
            If Me._label IsNot Nothing Then Me._label.BackColor = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overloads Property BorderStyle As BorderStyle
        Get
            Return Me._borderStyle
        End Get
        Set(value As BorderStyle)
            Me._borderStyle = value
            If Me._borderStyle = BorderStyle.None Then
                MyBase.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
                If Me._label IsNot Nothing Then Me.Controls.Remove(Me._label)
            ElseIf Me._borderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D Then
                MyBase.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
                If Me._label IsNot Nothing Then Me.Controls.Remove(Me._label)
            ElseIf Me._borderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle Then
                MyBase.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                If Me._label IsNot Nothing Then Me.Controls.Remove(Me._label)
            Else
                MyBase.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
                Me._label = New Windows.Forms.Label With {
                    .Height = 1,
                    .Dock = Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom,
                    .BackColor = Me._borderColor
                }
                Me.Controls.Add(Me._label)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: For the record, a "user control" is a class that inherits `UserControl`.  You created a "custom control".

Comment: Can you see the stack trace of the exception?  That will tell you exactly where it's being thrown.

Comment: Please see this image [https://ibb.co/dEvaBK](https://ibb.co/dEvaBK). I am on designer when I get the error. When I resize the control I get the error.